# mongoDB sorting not working with skip and limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am using query to find products from mongoDB collection. i am using different query filters with skip() and limit() everything is working great whenever i use sort with that it is not sorting the records "asc" and "desc" order.

here is my code

```
Products.find(filter)
        .sort({ column: order })
        .skip(parseInt(pageNumber, 10) * parseInt(nPerPage, 10))
        .limit(parseInt(nPerPage, 10));
```

Comment: With NodeJS driver see the usage of [sort](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#sort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will sort the results based on the column named "column", you need to provide the dynamic property.

Below is 1 way to create a sort object with the dynamic property then use it in the query.

```
let sort = {};
sort[column] = order;

Products.find(filter)
        .sort(sort)
        .skip(parseInt(pageNumber, 10) * parseInt(nPerPage, 10))
        .limit(parseInt(nPerPage, 10));
```

You can try this way too:

```
Products.find(filter)
        .sort({[column]: order })
        .skip(parseInt(pageNumber, 10) * parseInt(nPerPage, 10))
        .limit(parseInt(nPerPage, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use { column_name: 1, -1 } like .sort({ name: 1})?

Comment: yes the "column" and "order" are dynamic values that are passing.

Comment: function(column, order){
Products.find(filter)
        .sort({ column: order })
        .skip(parseInt(pageNumber, 10) * parseInt(nPerPage, 10))
        .limit(parseInt(nPerPage, 10));
}
something like that